# Publish Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I attempt to publish to Azure, a durable function, I am asked for credentials.

When I enter the credentials correctly the login screen disappears but the publish page does not advance and still requires me to log in.

I know my user ID and password are correct but just to be sure I used the wrong password and the screen says I've used the wrong password.

So I know I'm logging in correctly.

Is there any way to get other log information to see why I'm unable to publish my function to azure?

Also, in the upper right side of the dialog it does show that I am logged into Azure so I'm not sure why the additional login attempt is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio code, you can publish your project directly from there. Just got to add the Azure extension and login in. Maybe try that